# Do we need .NET framework for installing windows app in Client Machine?

Tags: c#, .net

Can any one help me regarding this ? Is it mandatory?

Comment: Do you mean just installing, or also running the application? You probably won't need it for installing (well, not 4.0, 2.0 will probably suffice).

Comment: Suppose if i have a Pharmacy application where i need to install in customer machine.Now does i need it or not?Will Microsoft OS provide any framework while instaling OS in clients machine?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which OS you have installed, you need to install a standalone of the .NET Framework.
At the moment there isn't an OS with the .NET Framework 4.0 installed, so you need to do it via the Windows Update or manual.
You can check out which .NET Framework is installed on this site: http://www.msigeek.com/2390/what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-which-version-of-the-os
The picture:
[image]

This means you need to install it on your OS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the client machine does not have the .Net framework on it you will need to install it.